# Running multiple user accounts on multiple displays simultaneously

Tags: mac-osx, apple, display, multiseat

Is it possible to set up a computer (preferably a mac pro) so that multiple users can log in at once, each on their own display with a different keyboard and mouse? We need this for a school setup in which 6-10 students will be using the same number of monitors and accounts connected to the central machine. The main goal is to have one central, easily updated machine and to save significantly on costs while running Mac OS X. Any other solutions to these requirements would also be welcome.

I can program, install hardware, or learn anything else fast if necessary.

Cheers and Thanks!

Comment: @those voting to close.  This probably doesn't belong on superuser, but does seem to or be similar to this [question](http://serverfault.com/questions/11283/good-multiseat-software-solution).  Although this question is more specific.

Comment: You may find this question about using setting up a [OSX terminal server](http://serverfault.com/questions/8966/mac-os-x-multi-user-thin-client-server-terminal-server) also helpful.

Comment: @Zoredache: Thanks for this link, I never heard about this product. Sounds really interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible with Apple hardware and MacOS.

The easiest way to do something like that would be a "Multiseat" linux system. X11 can handle this situation more or less easily, and there are many people who have this running successfully (as an example, see [this article](http://linuxgazette.net/124/smith.html)).

Of course, this doesn't offer MacOS as an operating system.

Comment: I don't know about *successfully.* They have a section at the bottom describing a bunch of different conditions under which the system would kernel panic and it doesn't appear that they ever came to a resolution.

Comment: Actually, I haven't read this article recently, just fished it out of my bookmark collection. I know I read different articles/news items about setups like this over the years so I guess some people got it working right. Nevertheless, I would only consider this whole idea as a last resort, preferring a terminal server like setup for schools, which is easy to do with Linux (and still impossible with MacOS).

Comment: @MarkM, the linked article is pretty old.  Someone was telling about much better results with a similar type of setup a few months ago.